# Sort index list in same way as list of pandas dataframes is sorted by length in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

Based on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72760325/sort-or-remove-elements-from-corresponding-list-in-same-way-as-in-reference-list#72760325) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72761755/sort-list-of-pandas-dataframes-by-row-count/72761757#72761757) I want to sort a list of pandas dataframes and based on the desired order (here `len`) I want to change the values of the `idx` variable in the same way as the values of `lst` are changed. Means if lst = [df1, df2, df3] and idx = [1,2,3] and the ordered list (by `len`) is `lst_new = [df3, df1, df2]`, then `idx_new = [3,1,2]`. A small example to illustrate my problem is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [11, 12, 13]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], ['x', 'y', 'z']]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

idx = [1,2,3]


lst = []

lst.append(df1)
lst.append(df2)
lst.append(df3)


lst = sorted(lst, key=len)

test = [i for j, i in sorted(zip(lst, idx))]
print(test)
```

gets the error message:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

Comment: I changed `A1, A2` and `A3` to the variable names `df1, df2` and `df3` in my example below. So it should be clearer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial try is good, just need the right key function to the sort. Here's how it can be done.

```
lst = [df1, df2, df3]  # Given the list of dataframes...

# Decorate each dataframe with its initial index
# and sort.
# Use a key that takes the length of the dataframe still.

#  Input here: [(1, df1), (2, df2), (3, df3)]
#  Output here: [(3, df3), (1, df1), (2, df2)]  (or whatever is the correct order)
lst_sort = sorted(enumerate(lst, start=1), key=lambda tup: len(tup[1]))

# now split the index and dataframe lists apart again if needed
# by using a trick where it feels like we use zip in reverse
indexes, dataframes = zip(*lst_sort)
```

If you want more examples, see the [Sorting HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) in the Python docs.

*Note: I've used `start=1` here to get 1 as the first index as in the question, but indexes in Python generally start at 0 by convention and because lists are indexed that way, so do consider using 0-based indexing if that's more convenient.*

Answer (score 1):

Found some more or less complicated solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [11, 12, 13]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], ['x', 'y', 'z']]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

idx = [1,2,3]

lst = []

lst.append(df1)
lst.append(df2)
lst.append(df3)


lst_srt = sorted(lst, key=len)

i = 0
idx_lst = []
for a in lst_srt:
    i = 0   
    for b in lst:
        i = i + 1
        if a.equals(b):
            idx_lst.append(i)
            break

print(idx_lst)

print(lst_srt)
```

with:

```
[3, 1, 2]
[   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  x  y  z,    a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9,     a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  11  12  13]
```